# Lemon Juice Expiration?

Tags: lemon, juice

My lemon juice went out of date almost 2 years ago. It has been in the fridge the whole time but has been opened. I'm just wondering if its safe to use? I want to put it in a cup of tea.

Answer (score 2):

If you've waited that long before needing a cup of lemon tea, I'm sure you can wait until you've had time to go to the shop for a new bottle ;)

Bin it, don't risk it.

The expiry date, btw is only for unopened. Once opened it will have a significantly shorter life - checking one from the fridge here it says "Once opened, keep refrigerated & use within 4 weeks" even though the full unopened expiry date is another year away.